# Read a column from excel file and replace it and write it in next column

Tags: python, file, file-io, rundeck

I Have excel file having list of numbers, in which i want to read this and replace `/` with `%3` with the numbers and write the replaced new parts in column 2 as in screenshot below

```
import requests
import json
import xlrd
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message='Unverified HTTPS request')

loc = ("/Users/Mac78908980/Documents/input_job.xlsx")
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet.cell_value(0, 0)

print('*************************Below is search Result**************************')
for i in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    url = "https://newUrl-test9.usspk05.app.xyz.com/api/89/issueNo/template?include=contractMap&PartNumber={}".format(sheet.cell_value(i, 0))
    payload = {}
    headers = {}
```

Input File:

```
Partnumbers
34353/A
32423/B
S34343/A
P45434/M
S4554/A
L34333/B
S89573/A
S92347/B
S03434/A
P23232/A
L34333/B
S89573/A
M73990/A
```

[image]

Desired

```
Col1           Col2
34353/A       34353%3A
32423/B       32432%3B
S34343/A      S34343%3A
P45434/M      P45434%3M
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since your problem statement is unclear, I only wrote a code according to your `Desired` output as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.read_csv("data/output_job.csv")
    df["New_parts"] = df["Partnumbers"].str.replace("/", "%3F")
    print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Result:

```
Partnumbers   New_parts
    34353/A   34353%3FA
    32423/B   32423%3FB
   S34343/A  S34343%3FA
   P45434/M  P45434%3FM
    S4554/A   S4554%3FA
   L34333/B  L34333%3FB
   S89573/A  S89573%3FA
   S92347/B  S92347%3FB
   S03434/A  S03434%3FA
   P23232/A  P23232%3FA
   L34333/B  L34333%3FB
   S89573/A  S89573%3FA
   M73990/A  M73990%3FA
```

You could replace `/` with `%3F` using `Series.str.replace`.

Comment: Thank you , I have a excel sheet having those serial numbers, i want to read that file having serials in Col1 and replace ```/``` with ```%3F``` of those serial and again write it in the same file, in another column(say Col2), thats the problem statement

Comment: In that case, it would be easier for me if you could provide few lines of values in excel column corresponding to the values in `Col1`.

Comment: hi, I have updated the problem statement with new values as well as screenshot to be clear, thanks a ton

Comment: @Bernard I have reverted my code to the initial version because I think that your desired output has not been changed.

Comment: Thanks @abysslover, but here we are not actually writing the updated one in excel right, we are printing it in console.

Comment: @Bernard I updated the answer to omit the index. It would have been easier for me if you had provided few lines of `input_job.xlsx` corresponding to Partnumbers.